# Query embedded document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I'm trying to query a **Group** document that has **Users** sub documents.

But I only want the subdocuments that belong to the user,

but I'm also getting data of other users.

Look at the query result, UserStatus field, only one of them belongs to the user.

The query result -

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5b1bcc12d5cdbf2cf78f2133",
    "name": "First group ever",
    "users": [
      {
        userId: 1,
        "userStatus": "I"
      },
      {
        userId: 2,
        "userStatus": "I"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Group.js -

```
const GroupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [{
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
            required: true
        },
        userStatus: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})
```

Query -

```
Group.find({
    "users": {
          $elemMatch: {
                userId: req.params.id, 
                $or: [{
                     userStatus: "I"
                }, {
                     userStatus: "A"
                }]
          }
        }
     }, "_id name users.userStatus",
     function (err, groups) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(groups);
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... can you please explain it bit more

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've updated the question. I want to get only one userStatus :)